# Why does sudo change HOME directory to /root on some Linux distros but not others?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, sudo, vim, home

In troubleshooting `vi`, I noticed on my Ubuntu installation running the command `sudo env | grep HOME` returns the home directory of the user that runs the command (`/home/USER`). But I noticed on my Linux Mint installation running the command `sudo env | grep HOME` returns `/root`. I have looked at `/etc/sudoers` on both computers and they are identical except for a `Defaults mailto=` entry. They both have `Defaults env_reset`. How does `sudo` determine how to set the `HOME` environment variable? I've seen elsewhere (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174587/471273) that `sudo -V` tells you which environment variables are preserved, but on both computers it just told my the `sudo` version and the plugins it was installed with. I also see in the `sudo` man page this section which makes me thing I need to ask how to view the security policy which I don't know how to do.

```
 -H, --set-home
             Request that the security policy set the HOME environment
             variable to the home directory specified by the target user's
             password database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may
             be the default behavior.
```

This is causing problems with loading `.vimrc` when I run `vim` as `sudo`. I could copy the `.vimrc` to the `/root` directory, but I am curious about this behavior and about `sudo`.

Comment: Related: [How to switch to root and use same dotfiles as my normal user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263403/how-to-switch-to-root-and-use-same-dotfiles-as-my-normal-user)

Comment: Thank you! I did not find that answer when I was researching. Probably cuz it referred to OSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu included [a patched version of sudo](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/760140) that preserved `$HOME` after `sudo` changed env preservation sometime around [2011](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-February/032490.html) (as far as I can tell... sudo's [changelog](https://www.sudo.ws/releases/changelog/) is a mess). Most other distros [didn't patch that](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302/comments/8). But in Ubuntu 19.10 [they changed to the upstream behavior](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/eoan/+source/sudo/+changelog), so it's interesting that your Ubuntu machine still has the old behavior (unless you just haven't updated in a long time, or overrode that somewhere).

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS but support for it ends April 2023. So I guess it's time to upgrade. I keep finding nuances to sudo so thank for explaining.